# Is less toner used, if you print only after the last page is spooled?

Tags: toner

> #### [Reduce Stop/Start Cycles](https://www.cartridgeworld.com/how-to-reduce-toner-usage-with-your-laser-printer/)
>
> In addition to waiting to change your toner cartridge, you can also avoid using stop/start cycles to further reduce your usage. During the stop/start cycle, toner will accumulate on the drum even if you are not printing anything. This is a wasteful practice that many people do not even realize their printers are doing. To avoid this, go into your “Printer Properties” tab on your computer and adjust the settings so that your pages will only start printing after the last page is spooled. This will reduce the number of times your printer will stop and start up again, saving you a lot of toner.

Who's correct in [this Reddit post](https://old.reddit.com/r/printers/comments/bbrbh4/til_to_reduce_toner_usage_print_only_after_the/?ref=share&ref_source=link)?
Many comments there rebuff the quote overhead.

[u/unclefisty](https://old.reddit.com/r/printers/comments/bbrbh4/til_to_reduce_toner_usage_print_only_after_the/ekkvgzw/)

> The amount of toner that will attach to an uncharged drum is pretty low.
> However this may reduce the amount of extra revolutions in the drum unit which will reduce wear.

[u/m0j0r0lla](https://old.reddit.com/r/printers/comments/bbrbh4/til_to_reduce_toner_usage_print_only_after_the/ekn5hnt/)

> I have worked in printing for 15, and this is just not true.
>
> In a toner based system, there is no toner on a drum surface in a
> resting state. In all toner based system, the drum(s) are *cleaned*
> after every page. This cleaning not only uses a blade to to physically
> remove the image, but most also use an erase lamp to take the charge
> from the drum surface.
>
> If you want to save toner, there should be a toner save feature in the
> print driver or in the printer settings.

Comment: I think this advice is akin to the idea that if you type less your keyboard will last longer.

Comment: @JakeGould, it's more akin to how do you make your keyboard last?  You make the mouse first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second comment that you quote, from u/m0j0r0lla, is correct.  Laser printers couldn't even work if the drum had a coating of toner before the image was applied to the surface.  It's the charge on the surface of the clean drum that attracts and holds the toner to create the image.  Everywhere on the drum that isn't part of the page content must be spotlessly clean or it will show up on the paper.  The claim about toner accumulating on the drum during start/stop cycles was written by someone who has no clue how laser printers work (despite the fact that it originated as a helpful hint on a cartridge remanufacturer's web site).

Also, spooling happens way faster than printing.  Once you start sending a print job, the printer doesn't finish a page, shut down, and wait for the spooler to catch up with the data for the next page.  Waiting for the last page to be spooled would have no effect on the printer starting and stopping.

Comment: Its worth adding that the original poster may have been confusing lasers with inkjets. Inkjets waste a lot of ink whenever the head is cleaned, which happens on startup at least.

Comment: @davidgo Maybe, but in general all of the quotes basically are along the lines of urban legends or “old wive’s tales”; a bit of vague “fact” is warped into a larger “truth.” Maybe this advice held true to some degree in the mid 1990s when laser printers first became commonplace for consumers, but not in 2019 or beyond. And that’s being generous in this assessment!

Comment: Hi again! Thanks. "Reddit isn't the first place I would go for reliable technical information. The initial quote that's the basis of your question is a case in point." Just to clarify - That quote isn't from Reddit?

Comment: @user1022717, 1. Good point.  The premise was from somewhere else, and the advice on Reddit was actual at least on the correct side of the issue, even if some of it was a stretch.  2. The information came from a cartridge remanufacturer.  Unbelievable.  I can only guess that they have non-technical people who post the helpful hints on their web site to give the appearance that their focus is on helping you save money.

Comment: We're lucky to have you then! Can you please edit the first para. of your answer in view of this?